# Can't import a random path of an image from a folder? (Java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I don't understand what is wrong with my code.. The program functions fine until I execute it using the "randPath()" method. I always get this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

My code is as follows:

```
package org.me.mycardapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;

public class CardDisplay extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public CardDisplay() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
    jPanel2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jPanel2MousePressed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/10_of_diamonds.png"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(267, 267, 267)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(343, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(24, 24, 24)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(47, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jButton1.setText("Change");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(343, 343, 343))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    jButton2.setText("Exit");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addGap(5, 5, 5))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jPanel2MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    jLabel1.setLocation(evt.getX()-63, evt.getY()-91);
}                                    

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(randPath())));
}                                        

public String randPath () {
    Random rand = new Random();
    String path;
    File file = new File("/org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/");
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    int r = rand.nextInt(files.length);
    path = files[r].getPath();
    return path;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CardDisplay.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CardDisplay.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CardDisplay.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CardDisplay.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CardDisplay().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Can you put the full stack trace in of the exception in your question please?

Comment: maybe there is a problem of paths - why dont you give it the whole path to File file = new File("/org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/") e.g. new File("c:/.../org/..")

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: If any of these answers worked for you would you be able to tick the answer which worked. This lets the author know their answer was correct and it lets others know the problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line in the `randPath` string.

```
File file = new File("/org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/");
```

Change it to the following line and it should fix the problem

```
File file = new File("org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/");
```

**Edit**

Upon running your code which you provided, I found the exception. The problem is your code shown below.

```
getClass().getResource(...))
```

You have two options. *`If you are using an IDE such as Eclipse and don't want to change code go for Option 2`*

*Option 1*

Change

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/10_of_diamonds.png"))); // NOI18N
```

and

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(randPath())));
}
```

to

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/10_of_diamonds.png")); // NOI18N
```

and

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(randPath()));
}
```

*Option 2*

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VzStS1b504) and it explains how to fix the problem in an IDE such as Eclipse.

This way you can keep your code the **same**, you just put your images inside a package as shown in the video

*Note: Sorry that a quite little kid presents it but turn the volume up because he explains it well*

Comment: While this was probably one of the problems in my program, I'm still getting the NullPointerException :/. I'm sorry to bug you with my issue, I'm new to Java and probably going a bit far for my experience. Thanks though!

Comment: @LesJespers I ran your source code and found the problem. Please look at the edit to my answer since your problem was not with the `File` it was with `getResource`

Answer (score 0):

Try to write exact directory. Instead of this `"/org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/"` try this `"c:/.../org/me/mycardapp/newpackage/"`. Fill the dots.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this:

```
 File file = new File("c:/.../org/.."); // enter the exact path
String[] files = file.list();
int r = rand.nextInt(files.length);
path = file.getPath()+File.separatorChar+files[r];
```

---

```
 File file = new File("c:/.../org/.."); // enter the exact path
File[] files = file.listFiles();
int r = rand.nextInt(files.length);
path = files[r].getPath();
```